# Need to run one dataset with different parameters each time in birt report

Tags: report, birt

I want to  loop dataset in birt report

Basically My requirement is I want run one dataset with diferent parameters but after running query data needs to print and after that with another parameters query should run.

Can we run one dataset multiple times.
In my case I want to run datset with two parameters `name` and one element of `idNoList` like `0` and need to repeat with same `name` and another element of `idNoList` like `1` given in belows json structure

The to be processed data structure looks as follows ...

```
{
  type: [
 {
    name: "20150401",
    idNoList: [0, 1],
  },{
    name: "13212",
    idNoList: [1, 3],
  }
]
}
```

I created two list box report parameters but that is not working with expectation

Answer (score 0):

### What you need to understand is BIRT's concept of *dataset parameters* and the difference between them and *report parameters*.

You can supply a value to a dataset parameter in different ways:

- By defining a default value for it.
- By binding it directly to a *report parameter*. But this doesn't work in your case because this is more or less only for scalar values and it doesn't allow to reuse the dataset for different inputs in the same report.
- By setting it in the `beforeOpen` event of the dataset. Here you can access all the context as you like.
- By supplying a value in the dataset parameter bindins dialog of the correspondig layout element. This option is useful for master/detail relations like DEPT/EMP in the classical Oracle example. Other reporting tools calls this kind concept "subreports".

Let me explain the last point (using the DEPT/EMP example and JDBC):

You would create two datasets:

Departments: `select DEPTNO, DNAME, LOCATION from DEPT order by 1`
Employees: `select EMPNO, ENAME, SAL from EMP where DEPTNO = ?`

The Employees dataset needs a dataset parameter, let's name it `param_DEPTNO`.

Create a list item in the layout and bind it to the Departments DS.
Add a grid with some information for the department to the detail section of the list item.
Then drag the Employees dataset into the detail section of the list item.
It's a good idea to name the list and the table items the same as their datasets.

Then go to the binding register of the Employees table item, click the "Parameter Binding" button, select the `param_DEPTNO` parameter,
and enter (or select using the helpers in the lower half of the dialog) the value: `row["DEPTNO"]`.
This supplies the parameter with the DEPTNO of the current DEPT row.

The idea does work with scripted or XML datasets as well, but it's more complicated unfortunately (disclaimer: I usually only use JDBC in BIRT reports).

### But as you tagged your question with "Oracle", there's a different and (IMHO) easier way:

Did you think about using Oracle's JSON SQL functions?
You can feed your JSON as a VARCHAR2 parameter into a JDBC query.
In the JDBC query, using JSON SQL functions, you can treat your JSON as if it was a table or view, similar to what's possible with XML and SQL.
It's definitely worth knowing this.
Once you know it, you can use common table expressions (SQL `WITH` clause) and use your SQL knowledge to handle all the data in the same dataset (without a subreport).